# uninitialized constant in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

So I've built a new controller = "Categories_controller.rb" and a new Model = "Category.rb" and now I would normally take my Savedfriend.rb model and use it with Category.rb model like so;

```
<%= category.savedfriends.size %>
```

However this time around I keep getting;

```
uninitialized constant Category::Savedfriend
```

It's driving me crazy. I do have models all set with belongs_to.

Comment: Is your "SavedFriend" class exactly in the `models` folder or is in it a subfolder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Rails convention, if you haven't specified your `class_name` on the association, it is going to look for a singularized, camelized version of the association name for the class name. If, for instance, you have a model `SavedFriend`, your association should be named `saved_friends`. If it can't find the class for the association, Rails tends to look for a scoped class within the class that's trying to call it. The error is a little obscure, but I've seen it plenty of times when I have a typo in my associations.

```
# in app/models/saved_friends.rb
class SavedFriend < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end

# in app/models/category.rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :saved_friends
end
```

Also, if your naming scheme for files and classes is as sporadic as it is in your question, you're going to have a bad time. File names should be lowercase and underscored, class names should be a camelized version of the file name. i.e. `Categories_controller.rb` should be `categories_controller.rb`, and the class should be `CategoriesController`. Similarly, `saved_friend.rb` should contain `class SavedFriend`.

Comment: my mistake on the file naming in the question, all my files are lower case :) sorry

Comment: @user2419316 It's not just the lower case, there should be underscores for each camel casing.

Comment: Edited answer to more explicitly demonstrate the convention and proper declarations.

Comment: you were right, I've had a typo in my `savedfriends` model .. had `class SavedFriends` where I needed to have `class SavedFriend`. Thanx!